# pytorchでTensorで一番値が大きいインデックスの場所以外の値を0にしたい

Tags: python, 機械学習, pytorch

Pytorchで3次元のtensorがあり、tensor中のdim=1の中で値が一番大きい場所を1に、一番大きい値以外を0にしたいのですがどうすればいいでしょうか？
ご教授よろしくお願いします。

torch.argmaxやtorch.max、スライス処理など色々考えてみたんですがわからなかったです。

#### 該当のソースコード

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(4, 3, 1)
print(x)
tensor([[[0.4082],
         [2.0627],
         [0.7252]],

        [[0.7946],
         [0.2679],
         [-0.4184]],

        [[0.3380],
         [0.8403],
         [-1.7227]],

        [[-1.1250],
         [-1.8144],
         [1.4441]]])
```

#### 以下のようにしたい

```
print(x)
tensor([[[0],
         [1],
         [0]],

        [[1],
         [0],
         [0]],

        [[0],
         [1],
         [0]],

        [[0],
         [0],
         [1]]])
```

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://qiita.com/hiroxile/questions/0c6f22541c62b388dbb7) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。そのようなルールがあることを把握していませんでした。申し訳ございません。以後気をつけます。

Answer (score 1):

御質問へのコメントに書かれている他サイトの回答を参考にさせていただきました。
（追記）コメントにて Python のグローバルインタプリタロックの影響を受けるので，記述例の中のリスト内包表記は使わない方が無難との御指摘をいただきましたので修正しました。どのような影響があるのかと別解もコメント欄に記載していただきましたので参照ください。

```
import torch

torch.manual_seed(17)
x = torch.randn(4, 3, 1)
# y = torch.stack([(a == a.max()).int() for a in x])
y = (x == x.amax(dim=1, keepdim=True)).int()

print(f'{x}\n\n{y}')
```

```
tensor([[[-1.4135],
         [ 0.2336],
         [ 0.0340]],

        [[ 0.3499],
         [-0.0145],
         [-0.6124]],

        [[-1.1835],
         [-1.4831],
         [ 1.8004]],

        [[ 0.0096],
         [ 0.1534],
         [-2.6631]]])

tensor([[[0],
         [1],
         [0]],

        [[1],
         [0],
         [0]],

        [[0],
         [0],
         [1]],

        [[0],
         [1],
         [0]]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

Comment: `torch.where(x == x.amax(axis=1, keepdims=True), 1, 0)`

Comment: @metropolis さん，ありがとうございます。

Comment: 理解されているかと思いますが、Python の GIL(Global Interpreter Lock)の影響(制御)を受けてしまいますので、list comprehension は使わない方が無難かと思います。(ベクトル演算ができなくなる、GPU を使用する場合に GPU <-> CPU 間の不要な転送が発生してしまう、等々)

Comment: @metropolis さん，御指摘ありがとうございます。追記させていただきました。